# Postgresql: psql: command not found

Tags: postgresql, 19.04

I installed Postgresql

`sudo apt install postgresql`

But `psql` is missing

```
$ type psql
type: Could not find "psql"
$ find / -name psql 2>/dev/null
/snap/core/6818/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/psql
/snap/core/6673/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/psql
$
```

How do I use Postgres if the command-line client is missing?

Comment: Install `postgresql-client`.

Comment: See above: `which psql` and `type psql` are almost equivalent; `type` is a shell built-in so is preferred.

Comment: install `postgresql-client` *doesn't* solve the problem.

Comment: what does it do though? does the install return as already installed, does it install or does it fail? I would be inclined to advise you`sudo apt purge postgresql -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean`  then follow these steps : https://tecadmin.net/install-postgresql-server-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Thanks; I tried what you suggested (which was similar to my previous attempts) but it still doesn't install a `psql` command.

Comment: I seem to have a problem uninstalling `sudo apt purge postgresql-11`; it dies with error

`Removing postgresql-11 (11.3-0ubuntu0.19.04.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/postgresql-11.prerm: 9: .: Can't open /usr/share/postgresql-common/maintscripts-functions`

`dpkg: error processing package postgresql-11 (--remove):
 installed postgresql-11 package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 127`

`Errors were encountered while processing:
 postgresql-11
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`